# sudo apt update Error The repository no longer has a release file

Tags: update, failure

I'm trying to update my Raspberry Pi to the newest version, but when running `sudo apt update`, I am getting practically nothing but errors.
(I'm running Buster)

```
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie InRelease
Err:3 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie Release
  404 Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Reading Package Lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. You are trying to use Jessie (which no longer exists). How did you get your system in this mess?

Comment: I don't know, the only things I had really ever done were some python and scratch projects

Comment: Edit: File manager just stopped working.

Comment: Just reinstalled the OS, hoping it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing I could do, I had to reset my system. At least I had not done much. If you are reading this, you could back up your personal files to a USB or the cloud and reset it.

Comment: Please remember to accept your answer. This prevents your question from showing up again and again. The option may not appear for another 12 hours.

Comment: it says i can accept my own answer in 9 hours